# why the remote path is not accessible by the python program?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have written a couple of functions to get the latest file. The code seems to be working properly, only that, instead of listing the files from the target path, it is listing the files from the location where the python program resides. Below is the code:

```
import os
import platform

path = '/tmp/'

def newest_file(path='.'):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    paths = [os.path.join(path, basename) for basename in files]
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        return max(paths, key=os.path.getctime)
    else:
        return max(paths, key=os.path.getmtime)

def stamp(newest_file):
    file_stamp = os.path.getmtime(newest_file)
    return file_stamp, newest_file

def file_compare(file_stamp, file_name):
    try:
        with open(f'{path}stamp.txt') as f:
            old_stamp = float(f.read())
        if old_stamp == file_stamp:
            print(f'No change: {file_name} --> {file_stamp}')
        else:
            print(f'New file: {file_name} --> {file_stamp}')
            logger.info(f'{file_name} --> {file_stamp}')
            with open(f'{path}stamp.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(file_stamp))
    except OSError:
        with open(f'{path}stamp.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(file_stamp))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    newest_file = newest_file()
    file_stamp = stamp(newest_file)[0]
    file_name = os.path.basename(stamp(newest_file)[1])
    file_compare(file_stamp, file_name)
```

So, instead of listing the files from '/tmp', its listing the files from '/opt', its where my python code resides.
If I use

```
`path = glob.iglob('/tmp/*.txt')`
```

and just use

```
def newest_file(path):
```

And remove the variables 'files' and 'paths' from the program, I get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_x20.py", line 45, in <module>
    newest_file = newest_file()
TypeError: newest_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

I have scratched my head, but not able to figure out the issue.Kindly help me find my mistake

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you define `path` as `'/tmp/'`, you're not actually using that value anywhere, because here:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    newest_file = newest_file()
```

You pass nothing to `newest_file()`, meaning it defaults to `.` as specified by your default kwarg, which is and should be the current directory of the execution.

And when you tried:

```
def newest_file(path):
```

That failed, because again, you're not passing anything to `newest_file()`, and now that it's a positional arg instead of a kwarg, it's required.